# How to get WordPress assets in wp_head() to serve via a CDN

Tags: wordpress, amazon-cloudfront

Currently my blog's asset path's outputted by functions like `wp_head()` are serving directly to the blog. How can I make the assets point to a CDN? Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few available plugins for this.  I would take a look at the following:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/cloudfront